# OpenID connect Signout request in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We have a web application implemented in Java/JSP and Azure AD single-sign-on authentication has been implemented using OpenID connect protocal. And the sign-in approach is working as expected, but the major issue is with sing-out. While signing out the user we are following the below approach.

1) User clicks sign-out button.
2) He will be redirected to application application sign-out page.
3) Clear the application session in sign-out page.
4) Then redirecting the user to Azure AD logout page, see below URL...

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout?
post_logout_redirect_uri=our_application_sign_out_success_page

The above approach is working as expected, but the problem is, if user copy and paste above URL in the browser tab when the user have a valid session in another browser tab, his AD session is getting cleared.

But the expected behavior is, the logout should happen only when user clicks the sign_out button.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior, the server is not able to detect whether the request is sent from clicking or paste in the address bar and navigate manually. And the server should'n care where is the request from, it only do the job you told it.

And if you have other applications also using the Azure AD as the identity data provider, the sign-out request will not affect the other applications when you sign-out from your web application. Also if you want to implement the single sign-out, you have to implement `LogoutUrl` in the web application and register it on the Azure portal.(refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code#single-sign-out))